невозможно создать форму Windows Forms в Visual C++
хочу создать проект на основе формы WinForms в Visual Studio 2022 (C++). однако при создании проекта на C++ нет возможности создать форму WinForms. пробовал включать поддержку C++/CLI - результата никакого. при чём, создать форму на C# получается без проблем.

На сколько я помню, только в более ранних версиях VS была возможность создать c++ приложение сразу с формой. В версиях постарше уже нужно самому подключать сторонние библиотеки, самая простая это Qt, есть возможность еще создавать формы с помощью  WinApi, но это посложнее

на стадии создания самого проекта (прямо с нуля) нужно выбирать как шаблон проекта Пустой проект CLR (.NET Framework).
и тогда создание формы Windows Form на C++ становится возможным.
